# How to redirect edit button to vf edit page and standred edit page based on record type

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have 4 contact record types ,among them one is a vf page ,others are standard pages ,currently i am able to redirect the standard pages to standard edit page ,but vf page is stuck on loop
VF Page

```
 <apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="TestContactEditController"  action="{!redir}">edit page code</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public class TestContactEditController{

private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
public Contact Con{get;set;}

public TestContactEditController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}    
 
public PageReference redir() {

    PageReference newPage;
    Contact c = [Select id, recordtypeid From Contact Where Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

    // visualforce page 1
    if (c.recordtypeid == '1234567890') {
        newPage = new PageReference('/apex/TestContactEditRT?id='+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));   
        newPage.setRedirect(true);
        return newPage;    
       
   
    // go to the standard edit page
    } 
    else
    {
        newPage = new PageReference('/' + c.id + '/e');
        newPage.getParameters().put('nooverride', '1');
    }

    newPage.getParameters().put('id', c.id);

    return newPage.setRedirect(true); 

   
}
```

}